Moving texlive distribution from one HD to another
My Texlive distribution is on C:\Texlive.
I need space and would like to move all files and directories to an another hard drive (like E:\users\me). I assume I can't just cut and paste the directorie.
How am i suppose to do an retrieve a fonctionnable distribution with all paths (i'm using TexMaker and Asymptote too) ?
Thanks.

you just need to move the directory and then reset your PATH. as far as texlive is concerned. You may have put the old path in editor configurations and other places which you will need to change as well
